# Inserting .csv file into linked list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I'm currently trying to input a .csv into my linked list. However when i run the code the
node->stationID = atoi(strtok(buffer, ",")); line works but then the next line gives me a "exc_bad_access" error. If I comment it out then the next line throws the error and so on and so forth. Looking up the error online it says that I must be point to a memory allocation thats not there. Not sure how to fix this. Example of the file is:

STATION_ID,STATION_NAME,Handicap_Accessible,Latitude,Longitude
40830,18th (Pink Line),TRUE,41.857908,-87.669147
40120,35th/Archer (Orange Line),TRUE,41.829353,-87.680622
41120,35th-Bronzeville-IIT (Green Line),TRUE,41.831677,-87.625826

And my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//Struct array for file 1
struct CTAStations
{
    int stationID;
    char *stationName;
    char *handicap;
    float latitude;
    float longitude;
    struct CTAStations *next;

};
typedef struct CTAStations cta;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    FILE *file;
    //FILE *file2;
    cta *current, *head;
    head = current = NULL;

    /*/For linked list in file2
    rider *rcurrent, *rhead;
    rhead = rcurrent = NULL; */

    //Open file 1
    file = fopen("stations.csv","r");

    /*/Open file 2
    file2 = fopen("ridership.csv", "r");
    if(file2 == NULL) {
        printf("Error! Could not open file. \n");
    }*/

    char buffer[64];

    memset(buffer, 0, 64);

    /*Testing to make sure file opens
    int c;
    file = fopen("stations.csv", "r");
    if (file) {
        while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
            putchar(c);
        fclose(file);
    }*/

    if(file != NULL) {

        while (!feof(file)) {

            cta *node = malloc(sizeof(cta));

            if(head == NULL){
                current = head = node;
            }
            else {
            current = current->next = node;
            }

            fgets(buffer, 64, file);

            node->stationID = atoi(strtok(buffer, ","));

            node->stationName = strdup(strtok(NULL, ","));

            node->handicap = strdup(strtok(NULL, ","));

            node->latitude = atoi(strtok(NULL, ","));

            node->longitude = atoi(strtok(NULL, ","));

             node->next = NULL;

        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("ERROR!");
        return -1;
    }

    //free(buf);
    fclose(file);

    //free(buf);
    //fclose(file2);

    //printf("Hello World\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Here's what it shows when i hit this error:

file = FILE *   0x7fff73da4050

node = cta *    0x100600140

buffer = char [64]  "144\r\n"

current = cta * 0x100600140

Comment: What does stepping through the code in a debugger tell you?

Comment: Sorry I'm eventually going to input another file into a linked list and posted that snippet instead. It's fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Your buffer is 64 bytes.

The last line of the input file snippet you posted is more than 63 characters long.

Fgets reads a partial line, reads the last bit of that line the next time through. There's not enough commas in the last bit alone, the strtoks fail, and it's all downhill from there.

Make your buffer large enough to hold your lines, and Always check your strtoks for success before processing the return value.

Also explains why buffer is "144\r\n" in the debugger. it's probably the end of one of the lines in the file after the first 63 chars of that line.

Pro tip: printing the contents of buffer in each iteration may have led you to this quickly. Stepping in a debugger may have helped too. Diagnostics printouts are one of your best tools, use them liberally.

Apologies for typos, on phone.

Comment: Thanks that helped! the first two lines of the file were throwing me off.     144 STATION_ID,STATION_NAME,Handicap_Accessible,Latitude,Longitude     I then put a loops to just print those out and move on to the data part of the file which I needed. I appreciate the feedback.